# need alternative for callback on .trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm using an onclick event on a menuitem in tinymce to .trigger a input type file in a form, (maybe not the best practice) to upload a file. only problem is that there is no callback on .trigger that I was going to use to do an ajax call.

here's the three snippets of code I'm working with

```
    <form id="image_submit">
    <input id="image_uploader" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png">
    </form>

    function submit_image(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "lib/cms/cms_switch.php",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {switch_id: 5},
            success: function(response) {

               alert('good');

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            },
        });
    }

    editor.addMenuItem("Upload Image", {
                name: "Upload Image",
                text: "Upload Image",
                context: 'tools',
                onclick: function(event) {
                    alert("here")
                    $('#image_uploader').bind('click', function(){
                        submit_image();
                    });
                    $('#image_uploader').trigger('click');
                }
        })
```

problem is that before a user selects a file to open, submit_image gets executed.

any ideas or criticism would be much appreciated

Comment: Huh?  Post code along with what you expect it to do vs what it actually does

Comment: why not bind `submit_image()` in `change ` event.? Instead of click.

Comment: thx you @shaunakde, that works. I'm not sure why though. I'm not familiar with the change event.

Comment: refer my answer below for details and links dont forget to mark it as correct if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event for `submit_image()`

```
  $('#image_uploader').bind('change', function(){
            submit_image();
   });
```

Change fires after file selection. Click fires on click of the input field.